# Windows Game project: Error: Could not load Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipline

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, xna

I have simply created one Windows Game project and ran without any change of the project, I am getting this error.

> The "BuildContent" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d.
>
> Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d5c3888ef60e27d' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all
>   its dependencies are available.

I don't know the details for above one. I am beginning game development.

Comment: It sounds like an installation problem. And XNA 3 is kind of old. Why not do a fresh install of Visual C# Express 2010 and XNA Game Studio 4.0?

Comment: any other reference website for XNA beginner developer